# Android: How to properly suppress Lint warning - "Consider using apply()" - when calling commit() on SharedPreferences.Editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I need to `commit()` rather than `apply()` my changes to my `SharedPreferences.Editor`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREFS_FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPrefsEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
sharedPrefsEditor.putBoolean("MY_BOOLEAN", true);
sharedPrefsEditor.commit(); // <-- I get the Lint warning on this line.
```

But Lint gives me this warning:

> Consider using **apply** instead; **commit** writes its data to persistent
>   storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background...

How do I suppress that Lint warning?

Adding `@SuppressWarnings("all")` before my method signature suppresses the warning, but is there a more specific String I can use instead of `"all"`? (Could not find anything [here](https://gist.github.com/Kurry/3c7e3993df9cdeab0535).)

Comment: If you are using Android Studio then it can help you add the suppress annotation. Move your cursor in your source code to the part that is highlighted as a lint warning (marked yellow) and that says `.commit()`, then press `option-enter` on Mac or `alt-enter` on PC. A context menu will open where you can choose to suppress the warning on the statement or function, etc.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks Rob!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@SuppressLint("ApplySharedPref")` works for me.

Any time you need to suppress a lint, what you have to do is to find the Lint issue id and pass it to this annotation.

You can find it by going to File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Inspections > Android > Lint. There you can search for the lint you want to suppress and, after selection it, you will be able to see its `issue id` on the `Description` area.